# Wired connection not being recognised in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: networking, 10.04, lan, wired

I have windows7 installed on my C drive and Ubuntu 10.04 LTS on my D drive. When I plug the LAN cable (ethernet cable) into the ethernet card of my laptop, Windows7 identifies the network correctly without the need for any manual settings and connects me to the network correctly.

Unfortunately, in Ubuntu, even after plugging in the cable, nothing happens (on the network side). It seems it is only scanning for wireless networks, and doesn't bother checking for the wired networks.

I tried adding a new wired connection and manually entered the physical address which was displayed when I connected to the network using Windows. I entered the physical address, and told it to use auto DHCP and saved in the Ubuntu network connection dialog box. Still there is no change; Ubuntu doesn't seem to recognise anything.

How can I get this to work with wired connections using Ubuntu, and why isn't my wired cable recognized by Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Install the `ndisgtk` package (and all the required packages)
- Select *install new driver*
- Navigate to your driver's cdrom and find the `.inf` file and click *install*. Should work 100%!
- Try to reactivate the network from network manager.